# What type of database back end for my mobile app (including GPS search capabilities)

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, react-native, geofire

I've created an app (react-native) that stores a users profile (age, gender, online status, lat/long coords etc...) in a google firebase realtime database. I then use a GeoFire function to find all the users that are within a certain radius of a given coord and then filter on those profiles (ie only find Males within X age range and are online) and then finally cut it down to the closest 100 profiles. This is done in a firebase function and returned to the users phone, so the most the user will ever download is 100 users which is acceptable for the application.

My problem is, as the app scales, there might be 10,000 users within the radius, so the GeoFire query grabs the key for all 10,000 users, then I have to go find the profile information for those 10,000 users and then filter on the logic, then cut it down to the closest 100. And this takes a huge amount of time now.

I feel like if I went to a traditional relationship DB on AWS I could put in a where clause on the first data pull and do the filtering and everything in one query.

Any help on the best way to tackle this, I've either used firebase incorrectly or have gone about this the wrong way.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't ask for database recommendations, they are explicitly off-topic. Ask what you can do to improve your specific use of Firebase…

Comment: You won't be able to put the data of 100 users in use (nor will you be able to visualize those informations on a single screen), so why do you even consider loading the whole profiles at once? Using GraphQL with Firebase would be appropriate in your case...

Comment: There is no way to do a Geoquery for the nearest 100 users. It's simply not possible to do that more efficiently that what you now do due to the way geohashes work. If you'd like to learn more about why that is, check out my (long) video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q

Comment: I'm not sure if firebase realtime database is what I need. Hence why I asked. Why would I keep using something that may be a completely wrong fit hence my ask? Also I'm not sure why it's a duplicate? I have solved the problem using firebase as mentioned in my post, I'm asking about a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can query your db using firebase.database with the limitToLast(100) method to limit your query, as in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query), like this:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("dinosaurs");

ref.orderByChild("height").limitToFirst(100).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {

console.log(snapshot.key);

});
```